# What do the numbers 206.835, 1.015, 84.6, 0.39, 11.8, 15.59 mean in the Flesch reading ease and Flesch-Kincaid grade level formulas?

Tags: syntax, grammar, applied-linguistics

I am looking to understand what do these numbers mean in the formulas, and how do they affect results, and why they were specifically chosen. Here are the formulas:

- Flesh reading Ease = 206.835 - 1.015*(total words) - 84.6*(total syllables/total words)
- Flesch-Kincaid grade level = 0.39*(total words/total sentences) + 11.8*(total syllables/total words) - 15.59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are fitted to an existing scale and have no particular meaning. They shall just reproduce an already known and gauged scale (just named "scale" in the [Wikipedia article on the Flesch-Kincaid readibility tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests).

Comment: Is there any paper or article where it is explained why those specific coefficients are used?

Comment: The wikipedia article has a link to the original paper of Flesch. But the coefficients are just made up to match a scale where a very easy text (easy being determined by other methods such as human assessment) has a score of 100 and a really difficult one a score of 0.

Comment: In other words, they don't have any validity out of context, and they certainly don't have three-place accuracy.

Comment: Got it, thanks.